# filter toolbar is not working for customized column, i.e i have used formatter in the column and filter is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used formatter in the column where I have changed `99999` to `System Role` and `100515` to `custom Role`. but when I use the filter on that column and search with system role or custom role it is not showing what should I do? Please advise.

I have used jquery `filtertoolbar` to search and filter in a column.

```
{name:'disabled_flag',index:'disabled_flag',label:"Disabled",width:100,formatter:disabled}

 function disabled(cellvalue, options, rowdata){
        var value;
        if(rowdata.disabled_flag===true)
            {
                value="Yes";
            }
        else
            {
            value='';
            }

        return value;

    }

jQuery("...").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });
```

Comment: With so small information nobody can help. Provide as much information as possible. jqGrid version used? jqGrid settings, demo data and etc? The best is to prepare a online demo  which demonstrates the problem

Comment: actually, I only want to know that I am modifying the data coming from the database in the frontend using formatter and editoptions value. so the data is changed and jquery filtertoolbar works on the index so it is not working properly. i am attaching the column and formatter below. I want to whether it will work or not?

Comment: It is really difficult to understand what you want. In order to help, prepare a demo with simple data to demonstrate the problem. The very important question here is: Where is performed the search - on the server or you have a local data where the search is applied.